# spring cannot access org.springframework.core.io.Inputstreamsource in list multipartfile

Tags: java, spring

I am a wholly beginner for spring framework.

A code below what I attached I have an error at `MultipartFile mf = fileList.get(i);`
The error statement especially I can see at under `fileList.get(i)`
The error says like title `cannot access org.springframework.core.io.Inputstreamsource`
How could I fix it?

```
public static boolean upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest mtfRequest, int attractionIdx){
    List<MultipartFile> fileList = mtfRequest.getFiles("file");
    String src = mtfRequest.getParameter("src");

    String path = "somepath";
    fileList.size();

    int size = fileList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        MultipartFile mf = fileList.get(i);

        String originFileName = mf.getOriginalFilename(); 
        long fileSize = mf.getSize(); 

        System.out.println("originFileName : " + originFileName);
        System.out.println("fileSize : " + fileSize);

        String safeFile = path + attractionIdx + "_" + size + "_" + i + ".png";
        try {
            mf.transferTo(new File(safeFile));
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependencies and change your import to like this

```
import org.springframework.core.io.*;
```